# bundle install - requires Ruby version >= 1.9.2?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I just started doing some development with a Ruby on Rails and trying to run the application locally. The app is working in a production environment with Ruby 1.8.7 installed.

I setup RVM on my computer with Ruby 1.8.7 as the default. But, when I try to run `bundle install`, I am getting the following error message:

```
Gem::InstallError: mime-types requires Ruby version >= 1.9.2.
An error occurred while installing mime-types (2.1), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install mime-types -v '2.1'` succeeds before bundling.
```

I tried looking for `mime-types` in my `Gemfile` but could not find it; which leads me to believe it's a dependency from another gem.

The weird thing is that the production server is also setup with Ruby 1.8.7 so I'm not really sure how the application was originally setup to run especially when `mime-types` requires Ruby version >= 1.9.2 to run.

**I can't find `mime-types` in my `Gemfile.lock` on the production server and therefore can't pinpoint what gem is trying to include it.**

Does anyone know how I can get this app to work locally so I can begin development?

I don't really have a lot of experience with Ruby or Rails.

Thanks in advance.

Gemfile:

```
source :gemcutter

gem "mongrel"
gem "ruby-debug"
gem "rails", "2.3.5"
gem "inherited_resources", "1.0.2"
gem "responders", "0.4.2"
gem "activerecord-sqlserver-adapter", :path => "vendor/plugins/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter-1.0.0"
gem "paperclip"
gem "ferret"
gem "crypt" # might need to install for system because of native dependencies
gem "active_scaffold", :path => "vendor/plugins/active_scaffold"
gem "render_component", :path => "vendor/plugins/render_component"
gem "unobtrusive_date_picker", :path => "vendor/plugins/unobtrusive_date_picker"
gem "acts_as_reportable"
gem "will_paginate", :path => "vendor/plugins/will_paginate"
gem "acts_as_transformer", :path => "vendor/plugins/acts_as_transformer"
gem "acts_as_paranoid", :path => "vendor/plugins/acts_as_paranoid"
gem "select_from_lookup", :path => "vendor/plugins/select_from_lookup"
gem "pdfkit"
gem "wirble"
gem "hirb"
gem "dbi"
gem "dbd-odbc"
gem "geokit"
gem "htmlentities"
gem "jeremyevans-exception_notification", :path => "vendor/plugins/exception_notification"

group :development, :test do
  gem "pdf-toolkit"
  gem "rspec", "1.2.9"
  gem "rspec-rails", "1.2.9"
  gem "mongrel"
  gem "mysql"
  gem "populator"
end

group :staging do 
  gem "mongrel"
  gem "ruby-debug"
  gem "rails", "2.3.5"
  gem "inherited_resources", "1.0.2"
  gem "responders", "0.4.2"
  gem "activerecord-sqlserver-adapter", :path => "vendor/plugins/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter-1.0.0"
  gem "paperclip"
  gem "ferret"
  gem "crypt" # might need to install for system because of native dependencies
  gem "unobtrusive_date_picker", :path => "vendor/plugins/unobtrusive_date_picker"
  gem "acts_as_reportable"
  gem "will_paginate", :path => "vendor/plugins/will_paginate"
  gem "acts_as_transformer", :path => "vendor/plugins/acts_as_transformer"
  gem "acts_as_paranoid", :path => "vendor/plugins/acts_as_paranoid"
  gem "select_from_lookup", :path => "vendor/plugins/select_from_lookup"
  gem "pdfkit"
  gem "wirble"
  gem "hirb"
  gem "dbi"
  gem "dbd-odbc"
  gem "geokit"
  gem "htmlentities"
end

group :test do
  gem "ZenTest"
end
```

Console Output:

```
Fetching gem metadata from http://rubygems.org/...........
Fetching additional metadata from http://rubygems.org/..
Resolving dependencies...
Using rake (10.1.1)
Invalid gemspec in [/Users/imaginationplus/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374@global/specifications/ZenTest-4.9.5.gemspec]: Illformed requirement ["< 3.0, >= 1.8"]
Invalid gemspec in [/Users/imaginationplus/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/specifications/ZenTest-4.9.5.gemspec]: Illformed requirement ["< 3.0, >= 1.8"]
Installing ZenTest (4.9.5)
Using activesupport (2.3.5)
Using rack (1.0.1)
Using actionpack (2.3.5)
Using actionmailer (2.3.5)
Invalid gemspec in [/Users/imaginationplus/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374@global/specifications/ZenTest-4.9.5.gemspec]: Illformed requirement ["< 3.0, >= 1.8"]
Invalid gemspec in [/Users/imaginationplus/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/specifications/ZenTest-4.9.5.gemspec]: Illformed requirement ["< 3.0, >= 1.8"]

active_scaffold at /Users/imaginationplus/gitlocal/cpo-core/vendor/plugins/active_scaffold did not have a valid gemspec.
This prevents bundler from installing bins or native extensions, but that may not affect its functionality.
The validation message from Rubygems was:
  missing value for attribute summary
Using active_scaffold (1.0.0) from source at vendor/plugins/active_scaffold
Using activerecord (2.3.5)

activerecord-sqlserver-adapter at /Users/imaginationplus/gitlocal/cpo-core/vendor/plugins/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter-1.0.0 did not have a valid gemspec.
This prevents bundler from installing bins or native extensions, but that may not affect its functionality.
The validation message from Rubygems was:
  ["README.rdoc", "LICENSE", "CHANGELOG.rdoc"] are not files
Using activerecord-sqlserver-adapter (1.0.0) from source at vendor/plugins/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter-1.0.0
Using activeresource (2.3.5)

acts_as_paranoid at /Users/imaginationplus/gitlocal/cpo-core/vendor/plugins/acts_as_paranoid did not have a valid gemspec.
This prevents bundler from installing bins or native extensions, but that may not affect its functionality.
The validation message from Rubygems was:
  missing value for attribute summary
Using acts_as_paranoid (1.0.0) from source at vendor/plugins/acts_as_paranoid
Using fastercsv (1.5.5)
Using color (1.5.1)
Using transaction-simple (1.4.0.2)
Using pdf-writer (1.1.8)
Using ruport (1.6.3)
Using acts_as_reportable (1.1.1)

acts_as_transformer at /Users/imaginationplus/gitlocal/cpo-core/vendor/plugins/acts_as_transformer did not have a valid gemspec.
This prevents bundler from installing bins or native extensions, but that may not affect its functionality.
The validation message from Rubygems was:
  ["README.rdoc", "LICENSE", "CHANGELOG.rdoc"] are not files
Using acts_as_transformer (1.0.0) from source at vendor/plugins/acts_as_transformer
Using cgi_multipart_eof_fix (2.5.0)
Using cocaine (0.4.2)
Using columnize (0.3.6)
Using crypt (1.1.4)
Using daemons (1.1.9)
Using deprecated (2.0.1)
Using dbi (0.4.5)
Using dbd-odbc (0.2.5)
Using fastthread (1.0.7)
Using ferret (0.11.8.5)
Using gem_plugin (0.2.3)
Using multi_json (1.8.4)
Using geokit (1.8.4)
Using has_scope (0.5.1)
Using hirb (0.7.1)
Using htmlentities (4.3.1)
Using responders (0.4.2)
Using inherited_resources (1.0.2)
Using jeremyevans-exception_notification (1.0.20100406) from source at vendor/plugins/exception_notification
Using rbx-require-relative (0.0.9)
Using linecache (0.46)

Gem::InstallError: mime-types requires Ruby version >= 1.9.2.
An error occurred while installing mime-types (2.1), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install mime-types -v '2.1'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Comment: Have you tried to put "gem 'mime-types'" inside your Gemfile and run again the bundle command?

Comment: Yes! It still returns the same error message :(

Comment: Maybe looking at the Gem that bundle was installing before it returned this error. Which one was?

Comment: I'm not sure. See my Gemfile and console output logs.

Comment: Try linecache19 instead of linecache.

Comment: linecache isn't even in my `Gemfile`

Comment: It is possible that one of the gems has been updated since the application was originally deployed, i.e. it has gained incompatible dependencies over time. You could try to specify the exact version of every gem. (or at least the ones requiring mime-types)  Look at `Gemfile.lock` from the production server to see which versions are installed.

Comment: Check Gemfile.lock. Which gem is requiring it?

Comment: Well this is odd. `mime-types` is nowhere to be found in my `Gemfile.lock`. What does that mean?

Comment: What happens when you run `gem install mime-types -v '2.1'`?

Comment: Hardcore the mime-types in your gem file `gem 'mime-types', '1.25'` . As mime-types 2.0 or version greater than 2 which requires ruby 1.9.2.

Comment: @FarhanAhmad Please post,how you resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

If you upgraded to **OSX 10.9 Mavericks** this might be caused by a leftover executable from an old version of bundler previously installed with ruby 1.8 and still present because bundler has not yet been installed for ruby 2.0.

Fix it by installing bundler:

```
sudo gem install bundler
```

Here's a complete investigation verifying that this is indeed the cause of the problem:

```
$ bundle install
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..........
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Installing mime-types (2.3) 
Gem::InstallError: mime-types requires Ruby version >= 1.9.2.
An error occured while installing mime-types (2.3), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install mime-types -v '2.3'` succeeds before bundling.

$ gem contents bundler
Unable to find gem 'bundler' in default gem paths

Directories searched:
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/specifications
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/specifications
/Users/yourusername/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/specifications

$ head -n1 $(which bundler)
#!/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby

$ sudo gem install bundler
sudo gem install bundler
Fetching: bundler-1.6.3.gem (100%)
Successfully installed bundler-1.6.3
Parsing documentation for bundler-1.6.3
Installing ri documentation for bundler-1.6.3
1 gem installed

$ head -n1 $(which bundle)
#!/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby

$ bundle install
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.........
Fetching additional metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Resolving dependencies...
Installing mime-types 2.3
Using bundler 1.6.3
Your bundle is complete!
Use `bundle show [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.
```