# Error while installing fog in ruby 1.8.7

Tags: ruby, fog, ruby-1.8.7

I'm working with fog under ruby 1.9 but in our new requirements we need to support ruby 1.8.x. I research and found this (https://github.com/fog/fog#ruby-187) that suggest adding:

> gem 'nokogiri', '~>1.5.0'

will solve my problem but I'm still getting this error:

> Gem::InstallError: mime-types requires Ruby version >= 1.9.2.

BTW, I try to install all the dependencies with this command:

> bundle install

Any advice on how to solve this?

Regards

Comment: This is a similar post, I think this will help

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21688128/bundle-install-requires-ruby-version-1-9-2

Comment: Odds are that something else is dependant on `mime-types`. That line, `gem 'nokogiri'...` is to help fix Fog's dependencies, but it's not going to help you with the multitude of other gems that probably won't work with 1.8.7. Why are you trying to support Ruby 1.8.7 in the first place? It's dead.

Comment: @meagar because my boss says so :P and BTW fog is the only gem with those dependencies problems

Comment: I suspect you could lock to an earlier mime-types (similar to specifying an earlier nokogiri above) to get it working. But I'm afraid I don't know what version mime-types dropped 1.8 support at. Pretty recent I think.